# Windows Batch counter with follow '0'

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, counter

Hi I am working on a small batch files that makes my rename files in a directory, so far the loop is working but I would like to make a `0` infront of my counter result as this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A counter=0 
for %%A IN (*.txt) DO (
    SET /A counter+=1 
    copy "%%A" "directory/%%A.!counter!.txt"
    )
```

This outputs perfectly as:

```
    tvscriptmonday.txt => TVscriptmonday.1.txt
    tvscripttuesday.txt => TVscripttuesday.2.txt
```

But I would like to have as output:

```
    TVscriptmonday.01.txt
    TVscripttuesday.02.txt
```

I tried using an `IF` command:

```
if !counter! <9 set counter=0!counter!
```

But somehow I could not get it to work, any ideas anyone?

Comment: in summary, use `if !counter! lss 9 set counter=0!counter!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a little trick:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A counter=100 
for %%A IN (*.txt) DO (
    SET /A counter+=1 
    copy "%%A" "directory/%%A.!counter:~-2!.txt"
)
```

the `:~-2` takes the last two chars from the counter only.

Expandable: for example, if you need a four number scheme, start counting from 10000 and extract the last four chars with `:~-4`

Comment: um, if the counter value is `1`, how would last two chars help? In addition, the linked duplicate already provides the answer.

Comment: @eis  Stephan's post gives you the last two digits.  It's a good solution.

Comment: thanks works :-) neat trick

Comment: @eis: the counter value is never `1`, because it starts counting with `100` instead of `0` And if you take the last two digits from `101`, it is `01` - `1` with a leading `0`, as desired in the question. Without having to check, if the counter is less than `10` or not.